# Comparar dos cadenas split de un archivo FILE

Tags: java, array, archivo, split

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual su objetivo es entrar en un archivo con File, leerlo y comprobar con un split si las dos palabras que están entre el símbolo "**|**" son iguales (letra por letra). He intentado hacerlo con un "charAt" pero no me sale del todo.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            File ips = new File("C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\e.txt");

            Scanner teclado=null;
            String texto="";

            try {
                teclado=new Scanner(new FileReader(ips));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (teclado.hasNextLine()){
                texto+=teclado.nextLine() + "\n";
            }

            String[] separacion = texto.split("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < separacion.length; i++) {
                String[] separacion2 = separacion[i].split("\\|");
                for (int j = 0; j < separacion2.length; j++) {

                }
            }
            teclado.close();
        }
}
```

En el archivo de texto tengo esto:

**Hola|hola**

**Hola|joya**

**Hola|Hola**

**Hola|Hole**

Comment: Pero has probado con el método equals() que hace esa comparación, o no lo quieres utilizar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas agregar  un salto de linea "\n" en realidad al leer el valor de cada linea usando `.nextLine()`, puedes realizar la comparacion por medio del metodo `.equals()` e imprimir el resultado.

```
   while (teclado.hasNextLine()){
                //Obtiene la linea de texto
                texto = teclado.nextLine();
                //Crea un array donde se almacenan ambas palabras.
                String[] separacion = texto.split("\\|");

                //Realiza la comparacion de ambas palabras
                if(separacion[0].equals(separacion[1])) {//iguales
                  System.out.println(separacion[0] + " es igual a " + separacion[1]);
                }else{//diferentes
                    System.out.println(separacion[0] + " es diferente a " + separacion[1]);
                }

            }
```

Este seria el codigo completo

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            File ips = new File("C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\e.txt");

            Scanner teclado=null;
            String texto="";

            try {
                teclado=new Scanner(new FileReader(ips));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (teclado.hasNextLine()){
                //Obtiene la linea de texto
                texto = teclado.nextLine();
                //Crea un array donde se almacenan ambas palabras.
                String[] separacion = texto.split("\\|");

                //Realiza la comparacion de ambas palabras
                if(separacion[0].equals(separacion[1])) {//iguales
                  System.out.println(separacion[0] + " es igual a " + separacion[1]);
                }else{//diferentes
                    System.out.println(separacion[0] + " es diferente a " + separacion[1]);
                }

            }
            teclado.close();

        }
}
```

tendra como salida

```
Hola es diferente a hola
Hola es diferente a joya
Hola es igual a Hola
Hola es diferente a Hole
```

Comment: Y yo haciendome lios con los "for"....Muchas gracias!